# How can I pass an object to jasper report as parameter?

Tags: jasper-reports, report

How can I pass an object to jasper report as parameter?

I want to send Employee object parameter to jasper report.
And set value to text field on report like:

```
P{employee.firstname}
P{employee.lastname}
P{employee.email}
```

How to create and set property for parameter variable in employee.jrxml?

How to call jasper API and set employee object to parameter?

Comment: Find a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684025/how-can-i-pass-an-arbitrary-object-to-jasper-report-as-parameter

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try using the Employee object as a JavaBean datasource?

Answer (score 0):

To send an object as a parameter, you have to:

- Define the parameter name and the type of the object in the .jrxml file
- Send a Map with the parameter

  `HashMap parameters = new HashMap<>();
  parameter.put("object", new Object());`
- In the .jrxml file you can use the parameter as following: 

  `<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{object}.getValue()]]></textFieldExpression>`

It works for me