# Add hibernate object as a parameter to jasperreports

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports, ireport

I am trying to add a hibernate object as a parameter to jasperreports.

I have added the appropriate import (inside my .jrxml file) but still cant't compile the report.

There is a suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684025/how-can-i-pass-an-arbitrary-object-to-jasper-report-as-parameter) to set a correct ClassPath in jasperreports's iReport settings but I can't figure out to which folder should I navigate the settings if I have simple web-application without third-party jars?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use JasperReports IReport, then is simple. You just have to add the **build** folder of you're applications, which contains all *.class files.

just go to `Preferences -> iReport -> Classpath`