# Field inside field on JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I am making a jsf application that generates reports using Jasper Reporting Tools. I am using *iReport* to design my report. I am wondering if *iReport* can accept fields that are inside other fields?

So i did this:

`$F{student.studentName}` inside my iReport pdf designer. The `student` object is a field in the `detRecord` object and `studentName` is a field in the `student` object.

Unfortunately, the *iReport* gave me an error like this when i tried compiling:

`et.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid :       1. Field not found : student.studentName`

Any ideas how i can pass objects with fields that also have fields inside them?

Comment: This is not a JSF problem but from iReport. AFAIK, you should pass primitive and String data to it or another parameters as sub reports.

Comment: i am very nooby with jasper, how i would do this?

Comment: I'm not an expert with jasper reports either, but you can always search on the net about it. For example, I just found these links: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2684025/1065197 http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/517039/can-i-pass-object-parameter-jasper

Answer (score 6):

Make students as bean, define getters and use it:

```
$F{student}.getStudentName()
```

Comment: i did this, but it doesn't work. I realised that i need to import the student class. How can i do this?

Comment: The only way I could get the above to work was if I set the report language to javascript instead of the default Java : Within Jaspersoft Studio, click the report and one of the report properties is "Language", change this drop down list to javascript.

Answer (score 2):

What are you doing? What means "it doesn't work"? Can you show stacktrace?

More explanations: 
1. Define field Student in iReport 
2. Define field class as yuor.full.package.name.Student for this field 
3. Drag Text field from palette to report
4. Set expression to this text field as $F{student}.getStudentName()